# the actress played mother

Tags: meaning

> Sarah Bernhardt travelled with her artist-lover Georges Clairin and a professional aeronaut in an orange balloon called Doña Sol, after her current role at the Comédie-Française. At six thirty in the evening, an hour into their flight, **the actress played mother**, preparing *tartines de foie gras*. The aeronaut opened a bottle of champagne, firing the cork into the sky; Bernhardt drank from a silver goblet.

Source: Julian Barnes. *Levels of Life*. Vintage 2014, p. 4.

I would like to ask what the part "the actress played mother" exactly means. Is it possible to understand it in the effect that the actress played a housekeeper as the official translator into my native language interpret it? – Why is the indefinite arcticle before "mother" missing?

Comment: "*Playing mother*" typically means "*to serve tea*". "Shall I be mother?" means "Shall I serve the tea?"

Comment: So it does not mean that SB portrayed the role of a housekeeper; she was just preparing the meal and drink for their trip,

Comment: Without further context, that would be my guess, but it's just a guess. We need a longer quotation.

Comment: It just means that she prepared the food. It's also a *play* on words since Bernhardt was an actress.

Comment: In your language, does the word you have translated *housekeeper* mean "a person whose paid job is keep a place clean and tidy" or does it mean "home-maker", a wife who does not have an outside paid job but whose traditional role has been to run the household, cooking and cleaning and doing laundry for her family?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It simply means that Sarah took on the role as the cook, a mother is assumed as the caretaker of the home and the primary cook (which may or may not be the case in this modern world).

The article 'the' is missing because it refers to the role of mother as an entity, it is not pointing towards someone in particular.

Answer (score 1):

From the context, it's fairly obvious that she was *acting in the role of* an actual mother, preparing food, etc. It is eminently clear that she is not onstage, and "mother" is such a common role in real life that this is really the only interpretation that works. It's certainly an exaggeration of what she did, but the difference is one of degree and not kind.